# Brainfuck interpreter not running some codes

Tags: c, interpreter, brainfuck

I'm kinda new to C programming and decided that making a brainfuck interpreter in C would be a good way to learn the language. I could write and tested with these bf codes:

this should print a hello world

```
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
```

this works as expected, so i thought my interpreter worked fine, but when I tested with a few variants of the hello world code, strange things happened.

this bf code should also print a hello world, but instead it prints out `²♣■■ÖFu ÖÖ■♦u`

```
--<-<<+[+[<+>--->->->-<<<]>]<<--.<++++++.<<-..<<.<+.>>.>>.<<<.+++.>>.>>-.<<<+.
```

this bf code should also print a hello world, but instead the program gets stuck

```
+[-->-[>>+>-----<<]<--<---]>-.>>>+.>>..+++[.>]<<<<.+++.------.<<-.>>>>+.
```

this is the code I wrote to interprete brainfuck:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("You must specify a file path\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //amount of memory locations available
    int mem = 30000;
    //creating an integer array with mem positions
    char arr[mem];
    //current memory position
    int index = 0;

    //setting everything to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < mem; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR, file couldn't be read\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //reading util the END OF THE FILE
    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '+')
        {
            arr[index]++;
        }
        else if (c == '-')
        {
            arr[index]--;
        }
        else if (c == '>')
        {
            index++;
            index %= mem;
        }
        else if (c == '<')
        {
            index--;
            index %= mem;
        }
        else if (c == '.')
        {
            printf("%c", arr[index]);
        }
        else if (c == ',')
        {
            scanf("%c", &arr[index]);
        }
        else if (c == '[')
        {
            char temp = fgetc(file);
            int skip = 0;

            while (temp != ']' || skip != 0)
            {
                if (temp == '[')
                    skip++;
                if (temp == ']' && skip > 0)
                    skip--;

                temp = fgetc(file);
            }

            fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        else if (c == ']')
        {
            if (arr[index] != 0)
            {
                fseek(file, -2, SEEK_CUR);
                char temp = fgetc(file);

                int skip = 0;

                while (temp != '[' || skip != 0)
                {
                    if (temp == ']')
                        skip++;
                    if (temp == '[' && skip > 0)
                        skip--;

                    fseek(file, -2, SEEK_CUR);
                    temp = fgetc(file);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot if you can help me out on this one.

Comment: Consider using [switch statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch)

Comment: @Ayxan, I thoughht about using switch's, but if's are easier to do at first, I'll probably change afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's could be a problem with this piece of code, when `index` become negative.

```
        index--;
        index %= mem;
```

`%` operator retains the sign of the left argument, so `-1 % mem` is –1, not mem–1 you may expect.

Comment: I changed this bit of the code to `index--; if (index < 0) { index = mem + index;}`, but now this code `--<-<<+[+[<+>--->->->-<<<]>]<<--.<++++++.<<-..<<.<+.>>.>>.<<<.+++.>>.>>-.<<<+.` gets stuck as well

Comment: You can solve it by `index = (index+mem) % mem;` or by `index += mem; index %= mem;`

Comment: Doing this did work, and it could run the second and third "hello world", but idk if it is just really slow but for some reason it does not run this exemple https://mitxela.com/projects/bf_tic_tac_toe :/

Comment: I found out what was making it so slow, apparently using too many file functions slow down the code. I've loaded all the instructions to an array and used it afterwards. Works like a charm. Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: @HenriqueSabino It seems you also missed this condition: `[` *if the byte at the data pointer is zero,..* In your interperter `[` is unconditional.

Comment: @Vovanium yeah, I coded so that every `[` leads to its correspondent `]` and then it checks if the byte at the data pointer is zero or not, if it is non-zero, it goes to the instruction after the `[`, I used this image to code the commands https://helloacm.com/wp-images/acm/2012/bf3.jpg

Comment: Uh, that's funny optimization